# How to calculate a total of values from other tables in a column of the select statement

Tags: sql, database

I have three tables:

- **CustOrder**: `id, CreateDate, Status`
- **DenominationOrder**: `id, DenID, OrderID`
- **Denomination**: `id, amount`

I want to create a view based upon all these tables but there should be an additional column i.e. `Total` should be there which can calculate the sum of the amount of each order.

e.g.

- order 1 total denominations 3, total amount = 250+250+250=750
- order 2 total denominations 2, total amount = 250+250=500

Is it possible?

Comment: And what's the SELECT statement you have tried (or are working with)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to guess your table relations (and data too, you did not provide any sample):

```
SELECT co.id, 
       COUNT(do.DenID) AS `Total denominations`, 
       SUM(d.amount) AS `Total amount`
FROM CustOrder co
INNER JOIN DenominationOrder do ON co.id = do.OrderId
INNER JOIN Denomination d ON do.DenId = d.id
GROUP BY co.id
```

Comment: I have tried this one but it gives the sum of all not row by row: -SELECT sum(d.amount) as TotalAmount from CustOrder o,DenominationOrder den,Denomination d where o._id = den.OrderID and d._id = den.DenID

Comment: @Fundi: edit your question posting sample data, we cannot work on what we think you have...

Comment: @Fundi: what is the query you posted as comment? It's wrong!! You have to use MY query, not yours!!! You use (at the end of your query) `AND o._id=2` so you get only order=2 !!! More: don't use `WHERE` conditions to replace `JOIN`, please !!!

Comment: @Fundi: no, it's not correct, you don't use `GROUP BY`.... please, use my query without changing it and you'll see it's correct :)

Comment: Yes sorry couldn't reply earlier. It is giving me desired results. Can you tell me one more thing. What if we want to assign value of this query to the column of the select statement. e.g. select (your query) as total,other columns.......

Comment: I tried in this way but its giving me sum of first and third order's amount in all rows:- `SELECT distinct o._id,c.BusinessName,r.Desc,(u.FirstName+u.LastName) as Name,h.IMEI ,o.CrDate, (SELECT SUM(d.amount) FROM CustOrder o INNER JOIN DenominationOrder den ON o._id = den.OrderID INNER JOIN Denomination d ON den.DenId = d._id GROUP BY o._id) as TotalAmount FROM CustOrder o,Customer c,Region r, AndroidUser u,Handset h,DenominationOrder den,Denomination d WHERE o.CustID =c._id AND c.RegionID = r._id AND u.RegionID=r._id AND h._id =u._id`

Comment: sorry please correct one thing in previous post. It's giving me sum of only first order in all rows!

Comment: @Fundi: listen, you asked us a question without giving us any smple data to work with. We (me and @MGA) provided working queries, but you're going on changing our queries with yours and asking us why they don't work... this is consultant fare... If you ask a question, you will be answered for that question; if you have a different question close this post (maybe accepting an answer if you think there is one correct) and open another question.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused and novice using the editor of this forum which may bother you! I never changed your query just once u asked me to post my query which I did. Anyway thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.CreateDate, COUNT(o.id), SUM(d.amount) AS 'Total Amount' 
FROM  CustOrder o 
INNER JOIN DenominationOrder do ON o.id = do.OrderID
INNER JOIN Denomination      d  ON do.DenId = d.id
GROUP BY o.CreateDate
```

[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66429)

Another way to do this, by using **CTE**, like this:

```
;WITH CustomersTotalOrders
AS
(
    SELECT o.id, SUM(d.amount) AS 'TotalAmount' 
    FROM  CustOrder o 
    INNER JOIN DenominationOrder do ON o.id = do.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Denomination      d  ON do.DenId = d.id
    GROUP BY o.id
)
SELECT o.id, COUNT(ot.id) AS 'Orders Count', ot.TotalAmount
FROM CustOrder o
INNER JOIN CustomersTotalOrders ot on o.id = ot.id
INNER JOIN DenominationOrder do ON ot.id = do.OrderID
INNER JOIN Denomination      d  ON do.DenId = d.id
GROUP BY o.id,  ot.TotalAmount
```

This will give you:

```
  id   |  Orders Count | Total Amount
-------+---------------+-------------
  1            3             750
  2            2             500
```

[**DEMO using CTE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66430)